# send data with ajax multi input

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I try to use `INSERT INTO` to `Database` using AJAX with multi input data, but I Face some Problem when I send data more than one `Input` Data. Did I Missed something?

This's **JS** file
**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function ajaxSaveTitle() {
'use strict';

var vTitle = document.getElementById('inputTitle').value;
var vPrice = document.getElementById('inputPrice').value;

var vTitlev = "vTitlev=" + vTitle;
var vPricev = "vPricev=" + vPrice;
var tXhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
tXhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById('linputTitle').innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
};
tXhr.open("POST","uploadfile.php","true");
tXhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
tXhr.send(vTitlev,vPricev);}
```

This is `PHP` file
**PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once('connect.php');
$currID = $_SESSION['user_id'][0];
if(!empty($_POST['vTitlev']) && !empty($_POST['vPricev']))  {

$fileTitle = $_POST['vTitlev'];
$fileTitle = stripslashes($fileTitle);
$fileTitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $fileTitle);

$filePrice = $_POST['vPricev'];
$filePrice = stripslashes($filePrice);
$filePrice = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $filePrice);

$qfileTitle = "INSERT INTO file (usr_ID, fileName, prc) VALUES 
('$currID','$fileTitle','$filePrice')";
if(mysqli_query($con, $qfileTitle)) {
    echo "Berhasil di Simpan";
} else {
    echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
};
mysqli_close($con);}
?>
```

Comment: Do you know how to ask the question? Sharing your code like everyone is free to read your code.

Show the errors, how you are sending data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use send like that:

```
tXhr.send(vTitlev+'&'+vPricev);
```

it accepts a string as params: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Answer (score 1):

You have to send more data with use of `&`

change your send code

```
tXhr.send(vTitlev,vPricev);}
```

to

```
tXhr.send(vTitlev+"&"+vPricev);}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of post requests, your data should be bind with "&". Comma is invalid as send accept only one parameter.

Look at this https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Data should be like this

```
 xhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
```

not this

```
 xhttp.send("fname=Henry,lname=Ford");
```